# Combining items in a list by pairs

Tags: c#, excel, list

I have a list containing multiple instances of a phone number. For each phone number there will be a minimum of two lines(one containing certain pieces of info, the consecutive containing the rest of info needed) There will always be an even number of instances for each phone number.
I am attempting to each entry by pairs i.e. entry 1 contains a,b,c,d ;entry 2 contains a,b,c,e
Looking to make a single entry of a,b,c,d,e

The code below is working in some instances but I am getting a few blanks in certain spots on output.

Any ideas?

```
{
    string phoneNow = i.Substring(0, 15);
    string redHair = i.Substring(15, 4);
    string blueHair = i.Substring(19, 16);
    string yellowHair = i.Substring(39, 161);
    string greenHair = "";


    ws3.Cells[row, 1].Value = phoneNow;
    ws3.Cells[row, 2].Value = redHair;
    ws3.Cells[row, 3].Value = blueHair;
    ws3.Cells[row, 4].Value = yellowHair;




    if (phoneNow == prevPhone)
    {

        if (multipleRecCheck % 2 == 0)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty((Convert.ToString(ws3.Cells[row - 1, 5].Value))))
            {
                ws3.Cells[row - 1, 5].Value = yellowHair;
                multipleRecCheck++;
                greenHair = yellowHair;
            }

        }

        else if (multipleRecCheck % 2 == 1)
        {

            ws3.Cells[row, 1].Value = phoneNow;
            ws3.Cells[row, 2].Value = redHair;
            ws3.Cells[row, 3].Value = blueHair;
            ws3.Cells[row, 4].Value = yellowHair;
            ws3.Cells[row, 5].Value = greenHair;
            multipleRecCheck++;
            row++;

        }


    }
    else if (phoneNow != prevPhone)
    {
        ws3.Cells[row, 1].Value = phoneNow;
        ws3.Cells[row, 2].Value = redHair;
        ws3.Cells[row, 3].Value = blueHair;
        ws3.Cells[row, 4].Value = yellowHair;
        row++;
        multipleRecCheck = 0;
    }

    prevPhone = phoneNow;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is some list object combining code i had, i hope it helps you

```
//Create new combined list
            SortedList<int, OrderData> combinedList = new SortedList<int, OrderData>();
            //Go through all orders
            foreach (OrderData order in Orders)
            {
                //check if paid, 6 = paid
                if (order.status == 6)
                {
                    int campingPlace = order.campingPlace;
                    //Check if the list already has an entry for the place
                    if (combinedList.ContainsKey(campingPlace))
                    {
                        OrderData b = order;
                        //combine orders
                        foreach (string bKey in b.cart.Keys)
                        {
                            if (combinedList[campingPlace].cart.ContainsKey(bKey))
                            {
                                combinedList[campingPlace].cart[bKey] += b.cart[bKey];
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                combinedList[campingPlace].cart.Add(bKey, b.cart[bKey]);
                            }
                        }

                    }
                    else // if not, add it to the list as is
                    {
                        combinedList.Add(int.Parse(order.campingPlace), order);
                    }
                }

            }
            return combinedList;
```